# How can I make an arrow thicker and save it for mobile usage in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am new to illustrator. Below is a screenshot of an arrow I am trying to make using illustrator. I need help in the following:
How can I make the lower part (curved part) of the arrow thicker/wider?
How can I save the image for mobile usage (within an app) in .png format?

[image]

Comment: Expand it and then manually adjust your curves

Comment: how do I manually adjust the curves to make it thicker?

Comment: @Scott: increasing the stroke width also increases the size of the arrowhead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To increase the stroke width, simply increase the weight in the **Stroke Panel**. If you want to adjust your arrowhead afterwards, simply alter the percentage used for the arrowhead on the Stroke Panel as well.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, and what about saving to use in a mobile app (.png format)

Comment: `File > Save for Web` and choose PNG.